# .bbl not produced, turns out biber fail to run

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber

I'm using `latex` package with Atom as my text editor running on Arch. I have installed `texlive-bibtexextra` and `texlive-most` just yesterday after reinstalling my borked PC. The previous system runs and generates everything fine, but now even running `biber` from terminal returns

```
syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/Pod/Usage.pm line 1, at EOF
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/vendor_perl/biber line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/vendor_perl/biber line 20.
```

In turn, no .bbl file is generated and `latex` fails to complete. I'm struggling to understand the error info above. Any help is appreciated!

**Minimal Example** (it returns nothing)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibsample.bib}

\begin{document}
  test \cite{bordelois88}
\end{document}
```

**bibsample.bib**

```
@article{bordelois88,
    title = {Causatives: From Lexicon to Syntax},
    volume = {6},
    issn = {0167-806X},
    url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/4047525},
    shorttitle = {Causatives},
    pages = {57--93},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    author = {Bordelois, Ivonne},
    urldate = {2021-11-23},
    date = {1988},
}
```

**Related**

Running `biber` itself returns the same error strings. I'm afraid it's a corrupted package but I tried removing and reinstalling but no avail.

Comment: welcome TEX.SE! you have to run `pdflatex main`, `biber main`, `pdflatex main`, `pdflatex main` to get the reference. And you have to put a `\printbibliography` at the end of document to print bibliography.

Comment: And which distribution of latex do you use on Arch?

Comment: I use the latest texlive available on pacman, as mentioned before, since I just installed the system yesterday.

Also, putting `\printbibliography` returns nothing since the `biber` package is stuck on it's own error.

Comment: well, I'm an Arch user but I install texlive from tug manually instead of pacman, and everything works will. Also I found that some scheme of texlive on pacman were flagged outdated. So what about trying installing from tug?

Comment: `syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/Pod/Usage.pm line 1, at EOF` end of file on line 1 sounds suspiciously like an empty file, that would indicate a broken perl installation rather than a broken biber you could try doing a forced re-install of perl using your linux package manager,

Comment: I agree. Turns out it's a broken perl installation. After running `pacman -Syu` everything works fine. Though I did reinstall from tug as Syvshc said. Thank you all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to type up a quick answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/Pod/Usage.pm line 1, at EOF`

End of file on line 1 sounds suspiciously like an empty file. That would indicate a broken perl installation rather than a broken biber. You could try doing a forced re-install of perl using your linux package manager, (`pacman` for your Arch linux)